# Can I use ASP.NET MVC model validation functionality without Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-binding

Can I take advantage of ASP.NET MVC model validation features (for example using [StringLength(n)] and other validation attributes on model class properties) *without* using Entity Framework?  I want to gain the benefit of this validation functionality during model binding but I want to use a different ORM for my data access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Model validation features such as `StringLengthAttribute` are attributes in the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace and have nothing to do with the Entity Framework. Just add the attribute to a property in your view model. For example

```
public class MyModel
{
  [StringLength(10, ErrorMessage="The name must be at least {1} characters"))]
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Readers should also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840603/can-i-do-asp-net-mvc-model-validation-without-a-view