# Can I do ASP.NET MVC model validation without a View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can I take advantage of ASP.NET MVC model validation (using DataAnnotations for example) without an MVC View (and hence without the automatic model binding magic that you get with a view)?

As an example I might have a webhook hitting a controller action directly - no view - and I populate my model manually, but I still want to get the benefit of the DataAnnotation validations on my model's properties.

Answer (score 5):

DataAnnotation is the part of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll that comes along with .Net Framework.

Please feel free to use it.

The example you are giving me it looks like you want to expose Business Logic through WebApi.

Short answer is Yes,  you can use.

However, on the top of it, have a look at expending your architecture by introducing WebApi, such that the code between MVC and WebApi is shared.

```
public class Recipe
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; } 
}


var recipe = new Recipe();
var context = new ValidationContext(recipe, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(recipe, context, results);

if (!isValid)
{
    foreach (var validationResult in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(validationResult.ErrorMessage);
    }
}
```

reference: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2011/06/29/manual-validation-with-data-annotations.aspx

[image]

Comment: TryValidateModel appears relevant here also...?  Also regarding your comment "The example you are giving me it looks like you want to expose Business Logic through WebApi.", this was not my intent, per-se.  Even though I am hitting my controller directly (no view), I am still not using WebApi in this case.  So might have been poor example on my part.